# No replacement done after , replace(u'\xa0', u' ', regex=True) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace `\xa0` with null in Pandas.
But No luck. How to get it right ?

**Input**:
`{'Team': 'ABE',  'country': 'USA', 'region': '\xa0Texas'}`

**Code** : `df1['area'] = df1['area'].replace(u'\xa0', u' ', regex=True)`

**Output**:`{'Team': 'ABE',  'country': 'USA', 'region': '\xa0Texas'}`

**Expected_Output**:`{'Team': 'ABE',  'country': 'USA', 'region': 'Texas'}`

Comment: It is quite confused since `df1['area']` is a `Pandas Series`, but the input sample is a `dictionary`. Do you mean that the series contain the whole dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is dictionary in column, so you need to dictionary comprehension for replacement:

```
df1['area']=df1['area'].apply(lambda x: {k: v.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for k, v in x.items()})
```